# Counting the same column value in multiple CASE clauses

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write a case statement which uses a shared column value across multiple when/then iterations, which isn't working because the shared value is only being counted in the first true evaluation. More simply, the logic for

```
select report_month,
       case when (payment_disposition = 'Free Trial' or payment_disposition = 'Pre-paid') then 'Gross Starts'
            when (payment_disposition = 'Payup' or payment_disposition = 'Pre-paid') then 'Net Starts' end as starts,
            sum(num_orders)
```

is only properly aggregating "pre-paid" payment dispositions into Gross Starts where I would like it counted in both. Is there a way to do this in a single query without nesting anything or writing a CTE to evaluate both cases separately?

The above query only aggregates the shared payment_disposition in the first definition evaluating to true, rather than both. I looked into doing a self-join on the table (so I could use one version of payment_disposition per clause in the case statement) but that returned entirely too many results to be meaningful.

Comment: [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96) - "In a searched CASE expression, Oracle searches from left to right until it finds an occurrence of condition that is true, and then returns return_expr." So it's doing what it's supposed to do; I *think* you already realise that, but it's unclear. Anyway... a [mre] would be helpful, with sample data and expected results. Which `starts` value would you expect to see for 'Pre-paid' - as it can't be both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to achieve this would be to join a subquery, and then select those results, or wrap the whole query making it a subquery and then building your results from that.

I haven't found a way of getting results from a column to another column.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation and have the data as two columns rather than two rows:

```sql
SELECT report_month,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN payment_disposition IN ('Free Trial', 'Pre-paid')
         THEN num_orders
         END
       ) AS gross_starts,
       SUM(
         CASE
         WHEN payment_disposition IN ('Payup', 'Pre-paid')
         THEN num_orders
         END
       ) AS net_starts
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       report_month;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(report_month, payment_disposition, num_orders) AS
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', 'Free Trial', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', 'Pre-paid',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01', 'Payup',      3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-02-01', 'Free Trial', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-02-01', 'Pre-paid',   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '1970-02-01', 'Payup',      6 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| REPORT_MONTH | GROSS_STARTS | NET_STARTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 5 |
| 1970-02-01 00:00:00 | 9 | 11 |

---

If you do want it as two rows then `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT report_month,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN payment_disposition IN ('Free Trial', 'Pre-paid')
           THEN num_orders
           END
         ) AS gross_starts,
         SUM(
           CASE
           WHEN payment_disposition IN ('Payup', 'Pre-paid')
           THEN num_orders
           END
         ) AS net_starts
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY
         report_month
)
UNPIVOT (
  num_orders FOR starts IN (
    gross_starts AS 'Gross Starts',
    net_starts   AS 'Net Starts'
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| REPORT_MONTH | STARTS | NUM_ORDERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | Gross Starts | 3 |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | Net Starts | 5 |
| 1970-02-01 00:00:00 | Gross Starts | 9 |
| 1970-02-01 00:00:00 | Net Starts | 11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4BEGPqan)